# How to calculate the probability of a combination

Tags: statistics

I apologise in advance if this is really basic since I'm not great at math.

Provided a set of 10 values (let's call the set chips and label its elements $a,b,c,...,j$) which have a weight which determines how likely they are to be selected. At the start of the selection process, all the elements are pooled together and 4 are pulled out one by one using the following formula:

$$\frac{Weight_{\text{Current Chip}}}{\sum Weight_{\text{available chips}}}$$

When a chip is taken out of the pool, it is no longer available hence the total weight decreases by the weight of the selected chip. What I want is to calculate the likelihood of a chip or multiple chips being present in the set of selected chips.

i.e.

chips $A$ to $F$ have a weight of 5,
chips $G$ and $H$ have a weight of 3,
chip $I$ and $J$ have a weight of 2

what are the odds that chips $A, G$ and $I$ are in the set of selected chips?

Comment: I doubt there is an easy approach.  Simulation will be noisy as the probability is going to be low.  You could consider the probability of each of the $168$ satisfactory ordered draws, which you could reduce to $72$ if you considered types of draw.

Comment: @Henry I am intrigued by your comment and somewhat confused about how to analytically attack the posted problem.  Could you please amplify your thinking around the computation of $~168~$ satisfactory ordered draws?

Comment: One satisfactory draw is ABGI with probability $\frac{5}{40}\frac{5}{35} \frac{3}{30}\frac{2}{27}$ and another is IABG with probability $\frac{2}{40}\frac{5}{38} \frac{5}{33}\frac{3}{28}$ and there are $166$ others to find

Comment: @Henry Your response clears the mist; my confusion occurred because I overlooked : "...all the elements are pooled together and 4 are pulled..." which drastically simplifies the problem.